# smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError has occurred when I tried to create an automated mailing code with python

Tags: python, email

```
from email import message
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

message = MIMEMultipart()
message["from"] = "jaibhamare@gmail.com"
message["to"] = "leenabhamare@gmail.com"
message["subject"] = "This is a python program"
message.attach(MIMEText("This is body", "plain"))

with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login("jaibhamare@gmail.com", "jaidadu99")
    smtp.send_message(message)
    print("sent")
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\files\email_tut.py", line 15, in <module>
    smtp.login("jaibhamare@gmail.com", "******")
  File "C:\Users\jaiba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 750, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "C:\Users\jaiba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Users\jaiba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 662, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at\n5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor z124-20020a623382000000b0050dc762812csm10594393pfz.6 - gsmtp')
```

I learnt this from codewithmosh.com and did exactly as he said but still getting an error>
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should actually read the error message.. 
it says that you need an application-specific password in order to send emails trough gmail from your python script. Thats probably because you activated two-factor-authentication for your google account. Just read the guide promoted in the error message, it tells you exactly what you have to do: 
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But even after deactivating 2 step verification as guided by google I am getting the same error

Comment: Google does not want you to disable 2fa, Google wants you to create an app-specific password